# Finding the probability transition matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Find $P_t$ when Q =
        \begin{bmatrix}
      -\alpha & \beta  \\
        \alpha & -\beta
         \end{bmatrix}

and $\alpha, \beta > 0$ satisfying the backwards equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find exp(tQ) to solve this problem.

Comment: By exp(Q), Do you mean exp(tQ)?

Comment: Yes exactly now I edit